# Filterable Isotope Gallery not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, jquery-isotope

I have created a filterable Isotope image gallery for a friend's website and I just can't seem to get the filter function to work. I have no idea why. I think that I have set up all the divs and classes correctly...

Here is the website: http://dariusdevas.com/wp/?page_id=214

Any thoughts? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

lose the dot
data-filter=".magic-bus"

Comment: Hello jenski. Thanks for the suggestion but after removing the dot the filter still doesn't work. According to [the isotope documentation](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/filtering.html) the dot is actually required. Any other thoughts? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for my poorly researched question. It was just a css problem where isotope wasn't being correctly referenced.